# JWindow region opacity

Tags: java, swing, screenshot, opacity, jwindow

I want to implement a screenshot functionality like in snipping tool. I can already select a rectangle and make a screenshot, but I this rectangle to be full opacity.

I wonder if there is a function in Swing or AWT which I can use like this:

```
window.setOpacityAt(Rectangle r, 0.5f);
```

I hope you got my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows: How to Implement Per-Pixel Translucency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#per-pixel).

[image: Partially transparent window]